# TCPIP under Win 3.11 on CPU>2.1GHz

Tags: windows, tcp

Background: On machines >2.1 Ghz, Win 3.11 cannot load protected-mode drivers for TCP/IP ("Wolverine") because of a timing problem in "IOS.386". There is a similar problem with Win95 and 98 1st release. There was a patch release from MS for 95/8, but never for WFW.

I found an old post here by Rob Cowell about this problem. He said that he used a different stack. I was curious about which one. I have made it work with the 16-bit DOS mode stack from MS, but it is a real pig for memory <640K. (Also, no native DHCP, but NBT does work, so you can map network drives. You also need to get rid of IPX & NETBEUI support for similar reasons.)

And just to prevent questions of the type "why would anyone want to ....", I'm trying to put together a WFW Live CD for modern hardware, just for fun. I did cobble together DHCP support using WATTCP modules and some complicated scripting before windows is started, but I need to be very circumspect about running any DOS programs or it runs out of low memory. (WFW actually sees 256 Mb of high memory; I was quite surprised.)

Comment: What stack did he use? And you are correct. I forgot to phrase it as a question. I guess I would not be any good playing "Jeopardy".

Comment: I'm not sure if by "stack" you mean the lowest level TCP/IP stack or the Winsock stack, but the first thing that popped into my head was "Chameleon Winsock", which was a popular package for Windows 3.x back in the day.  It may have replaced the entire TCP stack.

There was also "Trumpet Winsock" which rings a bell.  I vaguely recall using that with "slirp" and my school's unix shell account for ghetto dial-up internet.

Here's a link.  But good luck finding any of these packages.

http://www.chencompserv.com/ccs/seminars/winsock.htm

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close, because it's not programming related. But it is an interesting project to see if you can pull it off. I'd be keen to see a link or two to see how you go.

Comment: Will do. It may take a few months.